# Basic multithreading code not working as expected

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm new to multithreading and i'm having unexpected results with a very simple code:

```
    public void Run()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(() => myFun((i + 1)));
            t.Start();
        }
    }

    private void myFun(int threadNo)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Thread #" + threadNo.ToString());
    }
```

Can someone explain me why the code above prints this to the console window ?

Thread #3

Thread #3

Thread #3

Thread #6

Thread #6

Thread #8

Thread #9

Thread #10

Thread #11

Thread #11

Comment: Obviously I would expect Thread#1 Thread#2 ... 3...4...5...6...7...8...9...10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you're using a lambda which [closes over the loop variable](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx).

Restructure your code as such:

```
public void Run()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        int j = i;
        Thread t = new Thread(() => myFun((j + 1)));
        t.Start();
    }
}

private void myFun(int threadNo)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Thread #" + threadNo.ToString());
}
```

and enjoy the change.

Answer (score 0):

You could either use a "local" variable inside the loop like Jesse suggested, or you could instead use a parameterized start ([ParameterizedThreadStart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.parameterizedthreadstart(v=vs.110).aspx)):

```
public void Run()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(myFun);
        t.Start(i + 1);
    }
}

private void myFun(object threadNo)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Thread #" + threadNo.ToString());
}
```